# Wordpress 404 on style.css but not on all pages

Tags: themes, css

I have noticed an issue when running a site audit on all of my websites using SEMrush I picked up the error:

> issues with broken internal JavaScript and CSS files

Examples

> https://stage.fusionaccountants.co.uk/about-us/style.css
>   https://stage.fusionaccountants.co.uk/accountants-east-london/style.css
>   https://stage.fusionaccountants.co.uk/accountants-harrow/style.css

All the sites are WordPress and some use a child theme and some do not, the example site does use a child theme.

The style.css error is currently on 34 pages but not all.

I did update the permissions after editing the files but nothing has worked, the current permissions are dir 755 and the stylesheet is 644.

I am not sure what the issue is as it does not look like the permissions are the issue and if it was the child theme not loading the stylesheet then it would break across all the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the source of `/about-us` the culprit seems to be the contact form in the footer, present in more pages of your website.[Look here](https://prnt.sc/mt8luq).

Look at the Code module inside the divi builder, you'll see a `<link>` tag referring to a `style.css`: that's the code that's causing your 404. By the fact that the link tag is placed before a form I'm getting you wanted to style the form with some custom css? In that case just use the Divi theme options page and paste the css there, giving a proper id or class to the form.

Comment: Thank you so much I cannot believe I overlooked that. Everything is working as it should now.

Comment: Great! :) I see you are new here, if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have checked the answer and once again thank you this has solved the issue on all my sites that have the infusionsoft contact form.